# SciPy Curve_fit() doesn't fit curve

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

#### I made a random graph, and tried to use SciPy curve_fit to fit the best curve to the plot, but it fails.

First, I generated a random exponential decay graph, where `A, w, T2` are randomly generated using numpy:

```
def expDec(t, A, w, T2):
    return A * np.cos(w * t) * (2.718**(-t / T2))
```

Now I have SciPy guess the best fit curve:

```
t = x['Input'].values
hr = x['Output'].values
c, cov = curve_fit(bpm, t, hr)
```

Then I plot the curve

```
for i in range(n):
    y[i] = bpm(x['Input'][i], c[0], c[1], c[2])
plt.plot(x['Input'], x['Output'])
plt.plot(x['Input'], y)
```

That's it. Here's how bad the fit looks:

[image: .]

If anyone can help, that would be great.

MWE (Also available interactively [**here**](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/Refath/ExtractGraph/HEAD))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

inputs = []
outputs = []

# THIS GIVES THE DOMAIN
dom = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

# FUNCTION & PARAMETERS (RANDOMLY SELECTED)
A = np.random.uniform(3, 6)
w = np.random.uniform(3, 6)
T2 = np.random.uniform(3, 6)
y = A * np.cos(w * dom) * (2.718**(-dom / T2))

# DEFINES EXPONENTIAL DECAY FUNCTION
def expDec(t, A, w, T2):
    return A * np.cos(w * t) * (2.718**(-t / T2))

# SETS UP FIGURE FOR PLOTTING
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# PLOTS THE FUNCTION
plt.plot(dom, y, 'r')

# SHOW THE PLOT
plt.show()

for i in range(-9, 10): 
    inputs.append(i)
    outputs.append(expDec(i, A, w, T2))
    
# PUT IT DIRECTLY IN A PANDAS DATAFRAME
points = {'Input': inputs, 'Output': outputs}

x = pd.DataFrame(points, columns = ['Input', 'Output'])
   
# FUNCTION WHOSE PARAMETERS PROGRAM SHOULD BE GUESSING
def bpm(t, A, w, T2):
    return A * np.cos(w * t) * (2.718**(-t / T2))

# INPUT & OUTPUTS
t = x['Input'].values
hr = x['Output'].values

# USE SCIPY CURVE FIT TO USE NONLINEAR LEAST SQUARES TO FIND BEST PARAMETERS. TRY 1000 TIMES BEFORE STOPPING.
constants = curve_fit(bpm, t, hr, maxfev=1000)

# GET CONSTANTS FROM CURVE_FIT
A_fit = constants[0][0]
w_fit = constants[0][1]
T2_fit = constants[0][2]

# CREATE ARRAY TO HOLD FITTED OUTPUT
fit = []

# APPEND OUTPUT TO FIT=[] ARRAY
for i in range(-9,10):
    fit.append(bpm(i, A_fit, w_fit, T2_fit))
    
# PLOTS BEST PARAMETERS
plt.plot(x['Input'], x['Output'])
plt.plot(x['Input'], fit, "ro-")
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the concrete values of `t` and `hr` are missing. Nonetheless, considering the few data points, the fit looks good to me. Note also that you need more data points for a smooth plot.

Comment: Please don't add your perception of site rules to the question.

Comment: Your fit needs a better initial guess

Comment: Also, you don't need the loop: `y = expDec(x['Input'], *c)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you please clarify? 1) I'm not using an initial guess. I'm using SciPy to fit the graph. 2) I don't understand what you mean by that line of code. What is `*c`?

Comment: The splat operator unpacks arguments from an iterable. Curve fit has an initial guess to start the optimization whether you explicitly supply it or not. Read the docs to see what it is and decide if it's appropriate in your case

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. Perhaps more complicated than my problem is understanding why I have a -1 upvote, even though I added a MWE.

Comment: It's not a mwe if you have to go offsite to understand it

Comment: @MadPhysicist OK. I fixed it. Now, perhaps, the vote can be fixed?

Comment: I will remove the vote  because you have a reproducible example, but it's certainly not minimal. The amount of redundancy you have is pretty stunning, but the question is quite answerable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, I would like to rewrite your MCVE to use vectorized operations and only a single instance of the function computation. This will reduce everything to just a couple of lines. I recommend using a seed for repeatability when you do your testing as well:

```
def exp_dec(t, A, w, T2):
    return A * np.cos(w * t) * np.exp(-t / T2)

np.random.seed(42)
A, w, T2 = np.random.uniform(3, 6, size=3)
dom = np.linspace(-9, 9, 1000)

t = np.arange(-9., 10.)
hr = exp_dec(t, A, w, T2)

fit, _ = curve_fit(exp_dec, t, hr)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dom, exp_dec(dom, A, w, T2), 'g', label='target')
ax.scatter(t, hr, c='r', label='samples')
ax.plot(dom, exp_dec(dom, *fit), 'b', label='fit')
ax.plot(dom, exp_dec(dom, 1, 1, 1), 'k:', label='start')
ax.legend()
```

To explain the last plotted item, take a look at the docs for [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Notice that there is a parameter `p0`, which defaults to all ones if you do not supply it. That is the initial guess from which your fit starts to guess values.

[image]

Looking at this picture, you can pretty much see what the problem is. The starting guess has a much lower frequency than your data. Because the sampling frequency is so close to the oscillation frequency, the fit hits a local minimum before it is able to increase the frequency sufficiently to get the right function. You can fix this in a couple of different ways.

One way is to give `curve_fit` a better initial guess. If you know bounds on the amplitude, frequency and decay rate, use them. The amplitude will generally be a straightforward linear fit. The toughest one is usually the frequency, and as you can see here, it is better to over-estimate it. But if you over-estimate it too much, you might end up with a harmonic of the original data.

Here are a couple of sample fits that show different local minima in the optimization. The second one shows a harmonic case from over-estimating the oscillation frequency:

[image]

[image]

A decent set of starting parameters is the upper bound of your random range:

```
fit, _ = curve_fit(exp_dec, t, hr, p0=[6, 6, 6])
```

[image]

The green curve matches the blue so closely, you can not see it:

```
>>> A, w, T2
(4.123620356542087, 5.852142919229749, 5.195981825434215)
>>> tuple(fit)
(4.123620356542086, 5.852142919229749, 5.195981825434215)
```

Another way to to fix the problem is to sample the data more frequently. More data will generally mean a lower chance of hitting a false local minimum in the optimization. However, when dealing with sinusoidal functions, this does not always help because of how the matching works. Here is an example with 10x the number of samples (a fit with just 2x and the default guess fails entirely):

```
...
t = np.arange(-9., 10., 0.1)
...
```

[image]